# How to control button behaviors with RxJS?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Let's say I have a button and an stream that is a combination of multiple stream as following:

```
let button = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#button'), 'click')
let source = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(multiple_source, (...val) => val)
```

I want the following action:

- Click on `button`
- It will yield the latest value of `source`
- Stop `source` from keep yielding value when some inputs change until next `click` event
- Click on `button` again, `source` again yields its latest result
- And so on...

I have tried the following but not successful:

```
// `source` keep yielding values after button is clicked
button.flatMap( () => source).subscribe(val => do sth...) 

// `source` only yield values once but not yielding values 
// when some input changes
button.flatMap( () => source.take(1)).subscribe(val => do sth...) 

// `source` only yield values when button is clicked. 
// But like the above case, it stop yielding values 
// when some input changes
source.takeUntil(button).subscribe(val => do sth...)
```

Comment: do you mean you want to switch on and off your source?

Comment: @user3743222 it's exactly like joneshf answer

Comment: @user3743222 what operators do u usually use when you want to switch the source on and off?

Comment: I found this could be helpful too: https://egghead.io/lessons/rxjs-toggle-a-stream-on-and-off-with-rxjs Not sure if your approach is different. I'm keen to know about it.

Comment: no idea as I can-t access this - a paid link right? If you want an answer to that question, you have to raise another question. This is in order to keep with the Q&A nature of this site, and preserve its quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have found to work in this situation is [Observable#withLatestFrom](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/withlatestfrom.md). I am not sure if this is the best way, and it would be great if there were a simpler approach that was better. This is the tool I usually use though.

In your example, you could do something like:

```
button.withLatestFrom(source, (_, src) => src).subscribe(doSomething)
```

I just drop the button event since you do not seem to care about it in the example.

Here is a quick fiddle just for good measure. Hopefully this is something similar to what you were looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/pkoq9n6b/

Comment: I think `withLatestFrom` is the only solution in my case. I couldn't find any other operator that suit this case

Comment: Tks you for your updated answer. This is exactly what I'm trying to do.